# A question concerning BackgroundWorker

Tags: .net, multithreading, user-interface

I've just came across the following phrase on the internet (actually here http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx#_Using_BackgroundWorker)
"code within a RunWorkerCompleted event handler is able to update user interface controls without explicit marshaling".

Could anybody explain why doesn't code in this event handler need to be marshalled to main UI thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's marshaled.  You just don't have to do any *explicit* marshaling.  That is, you don't have to write the marshaling code yourself.  It's done automatically by the BCL code.

Comment: [Here's more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx) on how BGW uses `SynchronizationContext` to do the marshaling automatically for you.